# Entity Framework Core set column to nvarchar(max) with code first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core 7.0.0 and in my `OnModelCreating` method I am trying to specify a column to be of type `nvarchar(max)`.

In EF6 (not Core!), we were able to do something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Log>().Property(p => p.Errors).IsMaxLength();
```

However, I am not able to figure this out in EF Core. Is there something similar available in EF Core that I am missing?

I know that it would normally default all properties of type `string` to `nvarchar(max)` but I am overriding DbContext's `ConfigureConventions` with the following, to default all string to 50 characters:

```
configurationBuilder.Properties<string>().HaveMaxLength(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

- With help of `[Column]` data annotation:

  ```
  [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
  ```
- With help of Fluent API:

  ```
  entity.Property(p => p.Errors)
        .HasColumnName("YourColumnName")
        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)");
  ```
- [`HasColumnName`](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hascolumnname-method): the `HasColumnName` attribute is applied to a property to specify the database column that the property should map to when the entity's property name and the database column name differ.
- [`HasColumnType`](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hascolumntype-method): the `HasColumnType` method is applied to a property to specify the data type of the column that the property should map to when the type differs from convention.